# perform a function on first elements of list

Tags: haskell

In an attempt to write the Havel-Hakimi algorithm in Haskell, I wrote following function to subtract 1 from the first n elements of a list.

```
decrease_first :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
decrease_first 0 l = l
decrease_first n (x:xs) = (x-1):decrease_first (n-1) xs
```

This code works, but as I am trying to prepare for a Haskell-test and I was convinced this code is rather lame, I wanted to rewrite this function as follows:

```
decrease_first :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
decrease_first = map (subtract1) . take
```

I'm aware of the fact this does not do exactly the same, but I was just trying to understand partially applied functions etc. better and wanted to give this function a try. This turned out not to be the greatest of ideas, because I didn't get this compiled (type-definitions) and I am left with a massive mind-you-know-what, because next code does work, even though I considered it equivalent:

```
decrease_first n = map (subtract1) . take n
```

and this code fails again:

```
decrease_first n l = map (subtract1) . take n l
```

Moreover I tried looking for some nice way to apply a function to the first elements of a list, but I couldn't find anything. The first way is probably the most efficient way to do it, but I was wondering whether there was some way to apply any function on the first elements of a list. My idea eventually was to do something like:

```
decrease_first n l = map (subtract 1) (take n l) ++ drop n l
```

It works like this, but it doesn't look as nice as I had it in mind. So if anyone could help me resolving my type-issue, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `resolving my type-issue` - which one? You have shown so many functions

Comment: `decrease_first n l = map (subtract 1) (take n l) ++ drop n l` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye I only mentioned compilation problems for 2 functions (the others worked) and both seemed to be because of a misunderstanding of the composition operator. I'm sorry if it was too confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first point-free attempts don't work because `.` composes functions *with one argument*, while `take` takes *two*. What really happens is that code like

```
decrease_first = map (subtract1) . take
```

is equivalent to

```
decrease_first n = map (subtract1) (take n)
```

but now `take n` is not a list, hence a type error arises.

Instead, in

```
decrease_first n l = map (subtract1) . take n l
```

we have that `take n l` is a list, not a function. Here you need application, not function composition e.g.

```
decrease_first n l = map (subtract1) $ take n l
```

Your last attempt looks fine to me:

```
decrease_first n l = map (subtract 1) (take n l) ++ drop n l
```

As a variant, you can use `splitAt` to get `take`&`drop` together:

```
import Data.List
decrease_first n l = map (subtract 1) left ++ right
      where (left,right) = splitAt n l
```

or alternatively:

```
decrease_first n l = 
  (\(left, right) -> map (subtract 1) left ++ right) (splitAt n l)
```

which is not really better than the above ones.

Comment: Or alternatively: `decrease_first = (uncurry ((++) . map (subtract 1)) .) . splitAt`